# Turing & Computability & Computation

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, turing-machines

We know

[image]

if we have:

[image]

we can show  (T=t= Turin Redu.)

[image]

but i have no idea why this relation be correct? any idea?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Let us say that you have an oracle (a Turing Machine), that decides the language $(A\oplus B)\oplus C$. How can you decide the language of the RHS? Given $x$ as input, $x$ has to be equal to $0,1$ or $3$ modulo 4 (can you see why ?). If $x=0\mod 4$, one has to check if $x/2 \in A$, for this you have to forge an input for the oracle to check if $x/2$ is in $A$. Can you see how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prove that (for all $x$)

$$(2x+1)\in (A\oplus B)\oplus C \Longleftrightarrow (4x+3)\in A \oplus (B\oplus C)$$
$$(4x+2)\in (A\oplus B)\oplus C \Longleftrightarrow (4x+1)\in A \oplus (B\oplus C)$$
$$(4x)\in (A\oplus B)\oplus C \Longleftrightarrow (2x)\in A \oplus (B\oplus C)$$

Hence, ([see 1-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction#Many-one_equivalence_and_1_equivalence))
$$(A\oplus B)\oplus C \equiv_1 A \oplus (B\oplus C)$$

that implies Turing equivalence.